# Using Dplyr Filter to filter rows from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the Dplyr::Filter function.
I have a dataframe (top20_res) with a list of 20 gene names.
I have a seconod df, ‘gathered_group1_norm’ that has several columns, one of which is gene names.
I wish to filterr ‘gatherred_group_1_norm’ but the 20 geness found in ‘top20_res’, so that I end up with a new data frame that contains these genes and the other column data.
I thought the commannd would be:

```
df <- gathered_group1_norm %>% dplyr::filter(top20_res %in% gathered_group1_norm$ext_gene)
```

This seems to produce a df with the columns, but no actual data in it?

Answer (score 0):

We may do a join

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(gathered_group1_norm, top20_res, by = c("ext_gene" = "gene_name"))
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response. That comes up with the error X Problem with 'ext_gene'.
Should I make it gathered_group1_norm$ext_gene

Comment: @RobStaruch I thought you have `top20_res` had the same column name 'ext_gene'.  If it is different, use `by = c("ext_gene" = "yourcolumnname")`